# I used to press enter to get into my computer, but now Windows 11 requires I hover the cursor over it and click, enter does nothing

Tags: windows, microsoft

So I reboot 10x a day for whatever reason, whether it be because I'm on a few separate computers, whatever.

Windows 10, I press enter at the beautiful photo screen, and of course RETURN key presses the login button.

Windows 11, I press enter, and nothing happens at all. I even pressed it like 8 times. No reaction. had to click "login"

No password on the machine, it's not needed.

Comment: What do you mean by "No password" (how did you do this)?

Comment: Press the Escape Key and then enter.  That will show you the login screen.

Comment: @harrymc - “how did you do this” - I assume by setting a default user.